# Inserting Grease Pencil keyframes duplicates previous keyframe

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

I'm pretty new to using Blender so this might just be a dumb mistake on my part, but I can't figure out what's going wrong. Whenever I insert a new keyframe in grease pencil, it is not blank, and it just duplicates whatever is in the keyframe before it. This suddenly started happening today and I can't figure out why. It's making animating very difficult.

Comment: Are you sure it didn’t used to do this?

Comment: It definitely didn't use to do this. Whenever I put in a new keyframe it would clear out the strokes of the previous one. If I wanted the same strokes to be in the next keyframe, I would duplicate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you accidentally activated 'Use Additive Drawing'?

[image: icon Additive Drawing]

Comment: That is it! Thank you so much!